# GNS3: Map the console output of a router on GNS3 to a COM Port (Serial Port)

Tags: router, gns3

When a router is configured on GNS3 and started, it is possible to access the console output of the router by right clicking a router -> and then clicking `Console`

I need to be able to map this output to a virtual COM port (serial port) on the physical workstation. So that I can use terminal emulation software such as `HyperTerminal` to connect to the router as if it were plugged into a COM port of the workstation.

I need to be able to do this as a part of a project I am doing so that I don't need physical routers to demonstrate my project.

Appriciate any suggestions on how I could do this. Thank you for your time!

Comment: You can just telnet to localhost:2001 or 127.0.0.1:2001 or whatever the console port is. So you can use any terminal software you want to connect. Or what is your issue with connecting?

Comment: @DanielDib Thanks for the suggestion! However, I need to access the console of the router in GNS3 via a (virtual) COM port. The software I have talks to COM ports only. This way I can simulate it as if the router was connected directly to the workstation via a console cable to a COM port.

Comment: @slayernoah The Juniper/Cisco tags are reserved for when the question has something to do with those products.

Comment: @RyanFoley Sure thing. The only other 2 tags didn't have any followers. They were not totally unrelated since I was trying this on GNS3 with Cisco and Juniper routers. However, I managed to figure it out anyway and have written my findings too :). Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to do this by redirecting the localhost: of the GNS router to a virtual COM port using the following software:

1. [Virtual Serial Ports Emulator](http://www.eterlogic.com/Products.VSPE.html) - Freeware (32 Bit version is
   freeware. When installed on 64 Bit workstation, it asks for
   registration)
2. [Eltima Serial to Ethernet Connector](http://www.eltima.com/products/serial-over-ethernet/) - Commercial with a 14 day trial

Steps:

1. Find out the console port that the GNS router is accessible on: Right click the router and click on `Change console port`
2. Find out if you can telnet to it using Windows Telnet Client or Putty or similar. Use `127.0.0.1` (or `localhost`) and the port number found in step 1 above.
3. Install one of the software mentioned above.
4. Use the software to map the TCP/Telnet session accessed in step 2 above to a virtual COM port.

Screenshots of configuration:

**Virtual Serial Ports Emulator**
[image: Virtual Serial Ports Emulator]

**Eltima Serial to Ethernet Connector**
[image: Eltima Serial to Ethernet Connector]